# Why aren't gene drives extremely common?

Tags: gene

The ability for gene drives to sidestep the Mendelian mechanism and rapidly spread through populations (even if the gene is slightly fitness reducing) is extremely powerful. Why aren't normal populations riddled with parasitic gene drives?  What mechanism keeps naturally occurring gene drives suppressed to (apparently) very low levels?

Comment: You are going to need to provide references to back up the claim in your first sentence. If you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_drive), it is because you need to edit the genome of the organism in order to accomplish the task.

Comment: Yes, by "gene drives" I mean "gene drives".  As described by Wikipedia.  To introduce new artificial gene drives you need to edit the genome of organisms.  But gene drives also occur naturally. (Mentioned [here](http://www.wired.com/2015/11/gene-drives-explaining-technology-behind-malaria-free-mosquitos/), for example.) The question is, why don't these dominate? Edits made artificially by experimenters can also occur naturally.  (Or if they can't, why?)

Comment: From what they are describing, this is double-stranded break repair. You need a break to occur in the locus of the gene for it to happen. And as only about 1.5% of the human genome is protein coding, random breaks are more than likely not occurring in genetically important regions. For it to happen non-randomly you need an endonuclease to make a break in the chromosome. There are a few examples or genes where this occurs naturally, but more often times you see it as a viral mechanism to integrate into the host chromosome. It is estimated that upwards of 8% of the human genome is viral DNA.

Comment: And to be passed on, all of these changes need to occur in germ line (sex) cells. If they occur in somatic (body) cells, then either they will be killed by the immune system if they are deleterious, or they will just sit there until the organism dies and they are lost.

Comment: OK, but double-stranded breaks occur naturally, and you only need a handful (or even one) gene drive created through chance to take over a population.

Comment: Not without endonuclease activity. There is meiotic recombination that could easily delete the driver in the next generation, assuming that the gamete that had the mutation fertilized/was fertilized to form an embryo. Also if a gene is not under selection, especially when it comes to duplications, they rather quickly become pseudogenes through genetic drift. If the random driver confers a **significant** survival or reproductive advantage, then natural selection will select for it, otherwise it has far less of a chance of being maintained than the wild-type gene, as it is just a numbers game.

Comment: Are you saying breaks don't occur spontaneously without endonuclease?

Comment: Are you referring to the same thing as [meiotic drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiotic_drive)?

Comment: Spontaneous ds breaks occur and are repaired, but there are billions of possible locations that they can occur in higher Eukaryotes, so the odds of those breaks occurring in a productive way in the germ line without an endonuclease to specifically localize the break are slim. Also, there are other DNA repair mechanisms that do not go through Homologous recombination, such as non-homologous end joining, or even apoptosis (cell death) due to chromatin damage, that too reduces the probability even more. The key to the technology for synthetic drivers is specific breaks and providing template DNA.

Comment: Ok, you have started to sketch an answer, but its still not at all clear that those suppressive effects are nearly sufficient. Analogously, there are many ways that cells repair DNA and protect against cancer, and if you just listed those mechanisms and said "therefore it's highly unlikely cancer will ever develop", you'd be wrong. In the case of cancer, one can argue that the suppressive mechanisms will drive the rate to be low enough to allow procreation, but for gene drives there is no such argument (unless you go with group selection).

Comment: Compare: "The only way you can have a de novo mutation in the species is through a spontaneous event in the germline, and the chance that this would lead to anything useful is slim. Furthermore, there are lots of DNA repair mechanisms the cell uses which reduces the probability even more. Therefore, usefu de novol mutations cannot appear in a species."

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling that the OP is confusing naturally occurring so-called selfish, or parasitic genetic elements and the CRISPR/Cas9-based gene drives that have been making news as potential tools to eradicate disease vectors like the *aedes* mosquito. My answer is working from that assumption.

The big difference between naturally occurring "parasitic" genetic elements (including bacterial CRISPR elements and things like transposons) and the gene drives that are being tested as vector control revolves around what we put inside the latter class of gene drive.

The OP hit on this difference in his question, when he mentioned the decrease in fitness caused by engineered drives. In the naturally occurring drive-like elements, there is rarely ever a decrease in fitness in the organism and when it does occur, it is unlikely to be passed on to future generations.

Transposons, for instance, are largely active in somatic cells, whose DNA is not passed on to descendants. Semi-randomly occurring genetic changes are sometimes [passed on](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4107273/), but this is relatively rare and evolution favors those that are either neutral or that increase fitness. A brief search doesn't turn up, and I can't think of, any cases of naturally occurring deleterious genetic alterations caused by something like a transposon having been found to remain in a population long enough to be studied.

Engineered gene drives, on the other hand, particularly in the cases of those meant to combat mosquitos, are purposefully designed to reduce the fitness of their target host.

The last question, of what keeps naturally occurring drives at low levels, requires either a rather vague, or a very long answer. I'll go with vague and provide some links to longer ones. Briefly, our genomes have evolved a lot of ways to maintain genomic integrity, in the forms of proteins responsible for proof-reading DNA, repairing breaks, and destroying any "free" pieces of DNA found outside of a chromosome. We've also evolved a lot of mechanisms to maintain genomic integrity through small non-coding RNAs.

Here are some good papers (without paywall) on the subject:

1. [How p53 restrains mobile genetic elements](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26701264)
2. Proteins that function to restrain mobile genetic elements in [rice](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26243209)
3. Good [review](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24320156) of transposons in general
4. Finally, how people are [engineering gene drives to combat malaria](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25818303)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  In my defense, I don't think I confused anything so much as I just didn't state my question in the standard terminology.  This obviously is not my field, so thank you for filling in the gaps of my knowledge and answering the clearer version of my question.  Your paragraphs 2-5 point out that most naturally occurring parasitic gene elements have neutral, rather than negative, effects on fitness.  This is useful to know and much appreciated, but of course it just makes my question more pointed.

Comment: Paragraph 6 sounds to be essentially the sketch of an answer described by AMR in the comments on my question.  It may be that there simply isn't a clean, precise answer known.  But, as I pointed out there, an analog of this sort of argument exists for cancerous mutations, yet cancerous mutations are common.  And it does not explain the essential mechanisms by which lab-engineered gene drives can avoid these natural protections which are apparently so effective against natural parasitic genetic elements.

Comment: @JessRiedel - sorry for the radio silence. With respect to your original question, I wouldn't think of cancerous mutations as a 'gene drive'. Most cancers only occur after child-bearing age, so doesn't have much of an effect on an organism's fitness. That holds for both hereditary and acquired mutations, the latter requiring a long time to develop. Exceptions, like childhood leukemias, are interesting but quite rare.

Comment: Regarding lab-engineered gene drives, I doubt that they avoid cellular defenses, although it would be hard to measure that. Essentially, they overcome defense mechanisms by being targeted to a specific site and by carrying active payloads. That is, when they integrate, they do so in a functionally important location and deliver genetic code that has a measurable effect. This does not hold for many transposable elements. Although sometimes an endogenous TE gets lucky: http://www.the-scientist.com/?articles.view/articleNo/32298/title/Jumping-Genes-a-Cause-of-Cancer-/

Comment: To be clear, I am not considering cancerous mutations to be gene drives.  I was drawing an analogy between (a) the explanation suggested here for the rarity of naturally occurring gene drive with (b) an argument that cancerous mutations should not arise.  We know that (b) does not actually rule out cancer, so it would seem that, without further detail, (a) does not rule out widespread natural gene drives.